# In R, error converting to Date Class when Writing to a Table

Tags: r, read.table, write.table

example(s) are from the pretty fantastic book "David Manipulation with R" by Phil Specter, but an error comes up.

```
#write a gzipped csv file created from a data frame

gfile = gzfile("mydata.gz")
write.table("mydata, sep = ",", file = gfile")

#Goal is to test a conversion from char to Date objects with function textConnection()
sample = textConnection("2002-2-29 1 0 
                         2002-4-29 1 5  
                         2004-10-4 2 0")

read.table(sample, colClasses = c("Date", NA, NA))

Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

#next mydata = scan(unz("data.zip", "mydata.txt"))
```

Comment: This is why I always read in dates as characters and subsequently convert to `Date`s using a `format` string. That way I get some nice `NA`s for these cases and it's easier to investigate why those occur.

Comment: Btw., why would someone want to manipulate David? He's such a nice guy.

Answer (score 2):

Feb. 29th did not exist in 2002:

```
as.Date("2002-02-28")
#[1] "2002-02-28"
as.Date("2002-02-29")
#Error in charToDate(x) : 
#  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
as.Date("2004-02-29")
#[1] "2004-02-29"
```